# Fetch app alpha/beta version number from Google Play

Tags: rest, api, google-play

I'm looking for a way to programmatically fetch the alpha/beta *version number* (as a string) from Google Play, but it's not posted on the `/testing/` page for the app in question. Is there some other way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only reliable way to fetch the version numbers for the different tracks is to use the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks). However; this is only possible if you have developer access (which I was able to get in my case).